# NameError: name 'Log_in' is not defined (How can I fetch email and password from my table Sign_up)

Tags: python, django

I want to make user is valid or not by matching the email id and password form sign_up table if correct then login other wise thy need to log_in:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Log_in(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

class Sign_up(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

#views.py
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        email_check = Log_in.email
        pwd_check = [Sign_up.password]
        if email in email_check and password in pwd_check:
            return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'sign-up.html')
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. [Edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: Did you import the Log_in model in views.py

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel to deal with authentication, Django already has it builtin. Have a look at [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) and if it does not suite you very well it is designed so that you can easily [Customize authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/).